# SSRS - Display multiple pages of empty report

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2012, ssrs-2008-r2, ssrs-tablix

I'm working long time with SSRS and now encountered new challenge.

I have a report for A4 pages printing.
The report's designer is complex with a lot of tables, one after another, and the height of the main tablix is more than a single A4 page.

I used page breakers to make the report look good when printed, but sometimes a report can be with no data. So i added the "*NoRowsMessage*" property to the main tablix.

Now, the problem is that i have an empty report, with my "No Rows" message displayed and it holds 3 empty pages!

I tried to remove all report items.

I checked the widths and margins - this is not the issue.

I checked that "*ConsumeContainerWhitespaces*" property in true, but it still doesn't make the empty pages to disappear.

Is there anything i can do to make only one page to be displayed when there is no data?

[IMG1: no data report](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3XpFh.jpg)

[IMG2: preview 1st page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sa5eV.jpg)

[IMG3: preview 2nd page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5b6Wy.jpg)

Edit: I can hint how to recreate the problem: take a new empty report, add a list tablix, extend the height of the main list further from A4 limits. Run the report (from publish) with no data in your Dataset. It will display one empty page. Now go back to design and add a "NoRowMessage" to this main tablix. Run again the report and see multiple pages.

Comment: Can you show your report design, it's had to guess what the problem is just from the description.

Comment: I added steps how to create the problem, see the edit section at the bottom of my question.

Comment: If I understood to steps correctly, I don't understand why the tablix height is set to larger than the page size. Typically you would set any containers (rectangles, tablix, matrix etc) to be as small as possible as they will automatically expand to fit the contents.

Answer (score 0):

It seems there is a *tablix* inside the main *tablix* that is not hidden and it consumes space.

> I tried to remove all report items.

I will suggest a solution that works for me, not ignoring the facts you've tried to remove all report items and you have experience in *SSRS*.

Check if there is data not only in main *tablix*, but also in every *tablix* inside of it. If there is no data hide every nested *tablix* inside the main one.

For example:

There's a *tablix* inside *Additional data* column.

[image]

Choose *Tablix Properties* for every report *tablix*, the main one and all nested.

[image]

Then:

1. Choose card *Visibility*
2. Choose option *Show or hide based on an expression*
3. Click *fx* icon to set the expression

[image]

If not *tablix*, there is something that consumes that space, some row, or table. Ultimately, I would show entire *tablix* instead of message to see what is taking so much space and hide that item.

I hope this helps, it worked for me when I had similar problems.

Comment: Thanks for trying - As i removed everything from the report (except for the main list tablix) this didn't help me. I can hint how to recreate the problem: take a new empty report, add a list tablix, extend the height of the main list further from A4 limits. Run the report (from publish) with no data in your Dataset. It will display one empty page. Now go back to design and add a "NoRowMessage" to this main tablix. Run again the report and see multiple pages.

Comment: @Avsh Thank you for hint. I have managed to reproduce the problem but unfortunately I didn't manage to solve it. Alternative that comes to my mind is to hide main tablix if it has no data, using `=IIf(IsNothing(First(Fields!<some_column>.Value, "<main_matrix_name>")), true, false)` and show no data message as separate TextBox.

Comment: Yes, that what i finally did. I'm using Hidden expression: `=CountRows("MainDatasetName")=0` for the main tablix (or any other main space holder) and `=CountRows("MainDatasetName")>0` for the textbox with my No Rows Message. Thank you very much for your time and effort.

Comment: @Avsh No problem, I wish I could help.